# How to use Contours in OpenCV 2.3.1?

Tags: c++, opencv, vector, contour

I recently changed from using the C interface to the C++ interface in OpenCV. In the C interface, there were a variety of things that don't seem to exist in the C++ one. Does anyone know the solution to these problems:

1) In the C interface there was an object called a Contour Scanner. It was used to find contours in an image one by one. How would I do this in C++? Instead of finding all the contours at once, I want to find them one at a time.

2) In C `CvSeq` was used to represent contours, however in C++ `vector <vector<Point> >` is used. In C I was able to access the next contour by using `h_next`. Whats the C++ equivalent of  `h_next`?

Comment: +1 Good heavens! It's hard keeping up with the API changes in OpenCV, right?!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can get the contours one at a time.  But if you have a `vector<vector<Point> >` you can iterate over each contour as follows:

```
using namespace std;

vector<vector<Point> > contours;

// use findContours or other function to populate

for(size_t i=0; i<contours.size(); i++) {
   // use contours[i] for the current contour
   for(size_t j=0; j<contours[i].size(); j++) {
      // use contours[i][j] for current point
   }
}

// Or use an iterator
vector<vector<Point> >::iterator contour = contours.begin(); // const_iterator if you do not plan on modifying the contour
for(; contour != contours.end(); ++contour) {
   // use *contour for current contour
   vector<Point>::iterator point = contour->begin(); // again, use const_iterator if you do not plan on modifying the contour
   for(; point != contour->end(); ++point) {
      // use *point for current point
   }
}
```

Therefore to better answer your question about `h_next`.  Given the iterator, `it`, in the `vector`, the next element would be `it+1`.  Example Usage:

```
vector<vector<Point> >::iterator contour = contours.begin();
vector<vector<Point> >::iterator next = contour+1; // behavior like h_next
```